# When I Export my love2d game and I run it, its says that they are viruses and when I check it does "Trojan:script/Wacatac.B!ml"

Tags: lua, love2d

I was exporting my fourth version of one of my game using the LÖVE Framework and like always I did the same thing: All of the source to a .zip file, then renaming to a .love file, then check if the game works in the .love file, Then doing this command `copy /b C:\Users\sukyl\Documents\LOVE\love.exe + C:\Users\sukyl\Documents\LOVE\Island.love IslandExploiter.exe` (IslandExploiter is the name of my game) and when I run it, its says that its have a virus, after checking what it was "Trojan:script/Wacatac.B!ml"

Habitually, its doesn't do that

Comment: What antivirus do you use? What does VirusTotal say?

Comment: I don't have one, I use Windows Defender

Comment: If you want I can send you the source code

Comment: I'm doing a VirusTotal scan

Comment: It's most likely a false positive (meaning the antivirus thinks your program is a virus, but it's not). If you Google "Trojan:script/Wacatac.B!ml" lots of people are complaining about false positives. This probably means Microsoft didn't make the detection accurate enough.

Comment: heres the source https://github.com/suky637/IslandExploiter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to rebuild it. It was probably the zip was wrongly built so when I build it with the copy command, it think that it was a virus.